# Insert column name and its value into another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm having a small issue putting some codes together. I've looked around on this website with no luck. I know i have almost all what i need but still can"t put all of it together. Take it easy on me, I'm newbie with this... Here we go:
I have a table with a lot of fields :

```
tbl1 (id, col1, col2, DocId, ..., col50)
```

From which i need to put the information into another table :

```
tbl2 (id, id_doc, field, value)
```

What i need is to put for each DocId

```
row 1 = DocId in id_doc, col1 in field, col1_value in value
row 2 = DocId in id_doc, col2 in field, col2_value in value
```

...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE DocId IS NOT NULL";

if ($result = $db2->query($query)) {
$field_val='';
$value_val='';

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
foreach($row as $key => $value)
{
     // echo $key ." = " . utf8_decode($value) ."<br>";
    $field_val[] = $key;
    $value_val[] = utf8_decode($value);
}
}
$result->free();
}
```

As you can imagine, i can get the value in a string or an array for further use but my problem is i can't get to have the DocId next to each key & $ value for insertion.
Hope i'm clear enough and thanks for your help on this.

Hello again.
Just to let you know that i found a solution for my problem. Here's the solution that suits my needs if anybody would be interested.
First, i create an array with the columns names and i do "foreach":

```
 foreach ($cols as $col)
 {
 $query = "SELECT DocId, $col FROM tbl1 WHERE DocId IS NOT NULL";
if ($result = $db2->query($query)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo $row['DocId'] . ', ' . $col . ', ' . utf8_decode($row[$col]) . '<br>';

    }    
$result->free();
}
}
```

And voilà.
Thank you all for your time.
By the way, it's a very useful website :-) A++

Comment: Try `SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl1 INTO tbl2 WHERE 1=2`

Comment: is it one-time operation to convert db structure or you will need this query further?

Comment: It's a recurrent operation.

Comment: it shouldn't be recurrent operation

Comment: Well it's not that i have the choice... It's a part of an application. The purpose is to get the data from a file, put it in a temp table. Update the table with needed information then transfer the data from temp (where i'm stuck) to PROD table. lot of PROD tables are updated and i'm only stuck on this point.

Comment: There is an easier way to update your prod table from your staging table.  You just run an insert and/or update query.

Comment: Thank you Dan for your post. That's what i intent to do after i get the data as i want. Just for infos, i'm talking about thousands of records. It's for a batch process and need to be done as i described...

Comment: you are making 50 times more queries than needed

Comment: I'm open for suggestions. I know it's not the best way but that's what i've found till now. Would be more than glad to have your thoughts about how to improve my code. That's why i'm here anyway.